# i expected this code to create a range of buttons on the displaying screen

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout


class Stacklayout(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(0, 10):
            b = Button(text="bruh", size_hint=(1, 1))
            self.add_widget(b)


class TheLabApp(App):
    pass


TheLabApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `App` does not have a `build()` method, so nothing is built and nothing is displayed.

Try modifying your `App`:

```
class TheLabApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Stacklayout()
```

Comment: will i have to return every class i make?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.app.html#creating-an-application).